# Reanimated / Tap gesture Handler call does not update state

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I created an highlight component using Tap Gesture Handler and Reanimated, everything works great, but it won't work when we need current state of the class or the component, it takes initial state every time

Here is the component

**Highlight.tsx**

```
import React, {ReactNode} from 'react';
import {ViewStyle, StyleSheet, StyleProp} from 'react-native';
import {TapGestureHandler, State} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {Easing} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {
  timing,
  contains,
  useValue,
  useClock,
} from 'react-native-redash';

export interface Props {
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  underlay?: string;
  onPress?: () => void;
  children?: ReactNode;
  disabled?: boolean;
  state?: Animated.Value<number>;
  val?: Animated.Value<number>;
  onPressIn?: () => void;
  onPressOut?: () => void;
  testID?: string;
  onLongPress?: () => void;
}

const {
  event,
  useCode,
  block,
  cond,
  eq,
  set,
  call,
  onChange,
} = Animated;
const {BEGAN, FAILED, CANCELLED, END, UNDETERMINED} = State;

/**
 * Re Highlight
 */
export default ({
  onPress = () => {},
  onPressIn = () => {},
  onPressOut = () => {},
  style,
  state: st,
  val,
  children,
  underlay = 'rgba(63, 118, 230, 0.1)',
  testID,
}: Props) => {
  console.log('onPress:', onPress)
  // Animated Values
  const opacity = val || useValue(0);
  const clock = useClock();
  const shouldSpring = useValue(-1);
  const state = st || useValue(UNDETERMINED);

  useCode(
    () =>
      block([
        cond(eq(state, BEGAN), set(shouldSpring, 1)),
        cond(contains([FAILED, CANCELLED], state), set(shouldSpring, 0)),
        onChange(
          state,
          cond(
            eq(state, END),
            call([], onPress),
          ),
        ),
        cond(eq(state, END), set(shouldSpring, 0)),
        onChange(
          shouldSpring,
          cond(eq(shouldSpring, 1), call([], onPressIn), call([], onPressOut)),
        ),
        cond(
          eq(shouldSpring, 1),
          set(
            opacity,
            timing({
              clock,
              from: opacity,
              to: 1,
              duration: 100,
              easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
            }),
          ),
        ),
        cond(
          eq(shouldSpring, 0),
          set(
            opacity,
            timing({
              clock,
              from: opacity,
              to: 0,
              duration: 400,
              easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    [],
  );

  return (
    <TapGestureHandler
      onHandlerStateChange={event([
        {
          nativeEvent: {
            state: state,
          },
        },
      ])}>
      <Animated.View {...{testID}} style={[style, {overflow: 'hidden'}]}>
        {children}
        <Animated.View
          pointerEvents="none"
          style={{
            ...styles.overlay,
            opacity,
            backgroundColor: underlay,
          }}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </TapGestureHandler>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  container: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

I read useCode docs and added onPress, OnPressIn, OnPressOut as dependencies to useCode hook,

```
useCode(block([]), [onPress, onPressIn, onPressOut])
```

It will produce infinite loop if we set the state in onPress function...